# How can I find when a hard drive was manufactured?

Tags: hard-drive

I have some external hard drives that I need to know when they were made. Approximate year is ok. Is there a way to do this easily?

Comment: It's usually printed on the housing of the hard drive itself. You may have to open them up though. I'm not sure if there's a way to get it through software.

Answer (score 3):

1. Might be mentioned on the inside of the enclosure/case.
2. Easier solution would be to check their warranty status online. If the expiry date is shown then subtracting the number of years each drive is under warranty for should give you the approximate manufacturing year.
3. Ask the manufacturer by providing serial numbers.